# iphone development : how to deploy application to device but not run

Tags: iphone, objective-c

how i can deploy an application to iphone but not run the application. is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you build your app, then drag the binary and the provisioning profile into iTunes and sync your device, the app should install.

Answer (score 0):

Just hit the stop sign after it installs it.